# deactivate Compiz for a single window

Tags: compiz

I would like to deactivate Compiz for a single window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Compiz is a Window Manager so it's all or nothing. If it's non graphical you could switch to Ctrl+Alt+F2

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Partially.....

From previous Q&A
 [How can I use a .html file as desktop background/wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12690/how-can-i-use-a-html-file-as-desktop-background-wallpaper/26539#26539)

I'd like to add a neat trick to Sabacon's answer about using Prism...
You can turn Prism into a sort of widget by removing the windowframe. Add this line in Compiz - Extras/Windows Decorations on the Decorations Windows line add this to the end `& !(class=Prism)` This removes the windowframe for all Prism windows. You can do this trick for almost any window/Application.
Make sure there is a space before the & if there is anything else there.If not exclude the &.

This is what I use to remove the windowframe on all maximized windows and all prism windows `(!state=maxvert) & (!class=Prism)`