# How can I set an HTML page as the desktop background?

Tags: desktop-background, html, slideshow

Before people flag this as an exact duplicate of [How can I use a .html file as desktop background/wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12690/19675) please let me clarify .

Unlike that question where he just wants desktop icons for launching webapps , 
I want to use a HTML page as a background because I have a Slideshow as a HTML file which retrieves images from many sources . I want to be able to set this as a background just like in Windows XP. Is this possible ?

I heard from someone that I can use screenlets , but I would like to avoid that if possible.

**EDIT**

If not possible with Compiz or nautilus, what about with other display managers ? 
Gnome Shell, XFCE, LDXE etc ?

Comment: Just so you know, Compiz, Nautilus, GNOME Shell, XFCE, LXDE, etc. are not display managers.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with Nautilus or Compiz, no. I don't know what exactly the screenlets you are talking about are, but the general answer is no. File managers and the window manager, do not use a webkit view to draw the background and icons. This works in Windows, because the file manager and web browser, are the same thing. In Ubuntu, they aren't.

Comment: In Windows 7, I'm not sure if this is possible anymore either. Since in Windows 7, you have the ability to "disable" Internet Explorer, I _think_ they went ahead and removed the dependency on Windows Explorer to Internet Explorer, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question...but I just made this ([BackgroundPage](https://github.com/CiaccoDavide/BackgroundPage)):

- http://ciaccodavi.de/BackgroundPage/
- or https://github.com/CiaccoDavide/BackgroundPage/tree/master/docs

I tried it on Debian and Lubuntu and it works, but I couldn't build a release for Linux...

You can try using the source code in Qt